# Salt usage for Spring security?

Tags: passwords, web-application, aes, java

I use the [Spring security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) for Java web applications and I have written an authentication provider which is working without salt and now I want to either add salt or alternatively use the built-in algorithms with Spring security that appear to be SHA and that can use salt that is specified with XML. In my case I didn't use SHA but AES and the input password is matched against cryptographic string that were encoded e.g. `�[�s�E�`qh�%"5%��g"2T��$�` that will match against back-end in this handler.

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        AdministratorAccount administratorAccount = administratorAccountService.get(name);
        CryptographyProviderAES256 aes256CryptographyProvider = new CryptographyProviderAES256(256);
        byte[] mockSecretCode = new StringBuilder().append("qwertyuiqwertyui").toString().getBytes();
        byte[] encrypted = aes256CryptographyProvider.encrypt(password.getBytes(), mockSecretCode);

        //TODO: salt
        if (administratorAccount.getPassword().equals(new String(encrypted))) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
            return auth;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Should I use SHA instead that is built-in with Spring security and can be added with XML instead? My Account class has variables for password and salt, how should I implement a salt? Should I generate a salt from time + random when creating the account like this:

```
 final Random r = new SecureRandom();
 byte[] salt = new byte[32];
 r.nextBytes(salt);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do yourself a favour, don't try to invent your own password hashing functions. In the field of cryptography in general, and of password hashing in particular, amateur constructions are almost invariably weak, because **you cannot test for security**. Any programmer can make some code which is *sound*, i.e. which works, but no programmer can make sure that what he produced is *secure*.

Professional cryptographers cannot invent secure algorithms by themselves either; however, they *know it*. So when they produce a new algorithm, they show it to their fellow cryptographers, who do their best to try to break it. If the algorithm survives for sufficient time (several *years*), then the algorithm is deemed "probably secure enough to be used in production".

Unless you have your own cryptographer team and can afford to wait for a few years, you really need to rely on *existing* password hashing functions which have undergone this treatment and are still alive to talk about it. This basically means bcrypt or PBKDF2. More details [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846).

Also, don't use `password.getBytes()`. That `getBytes()` method uses the default charset, which depends on the current locale. This method is a great way to make code which breaks when used in another country. Instead, use an explicit charset, as in `password.getBytes("UTF-8")`.